# Autogenerate wordpress shortcodes using array?

Tags: plugins, functions, shortcode, actions, array

I was create a shortcode which automatically generate shortcodes with given array key and value. Function names does not generate dynamically.

Note: Array KEY = ShortcodeName and Value = Wordpress Option field.

```
add_shortcode("auto_gen", "auto_gen");
function auto_gen() {
    $a = array(
        "get_address"       =>  "mg_admin_address",
        "get_phone"         =>  "mg_admin_phone",
        "get_fax"           =>  "mg_admin_fax",
        "get_email"         =>  "mg_admin_email",
        "get_hrs_mon"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_mon_frd",
        "get_hrs_sat"       =>  "mg_work_hrs_sat"
    );
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if(has_shortcode($k)) {
            echo "<br>Found: ". $k;
        } else {
            add_shortcode($k,  $k. "_init");
            function $k. "_init"() {
                return get_option[$v, ''];
            }
        }
        add_shortcode();
        echo $k ." -> ". $v. "<br />";
    }
}
```

There is any possible way to do this.

**NOTE:**

> Here, get_address array key is a shortcode. And it is dynamically generate when It pass though loop. get_address is changable. If I change get_address with get_user_address then get_user_address generate generated. "get_address", "get_phone" are CHANGABLE at END LEVEL.

Developer also generate shortcodes to access created wp_options useing get_options, simply pushing elements in array. e.g. "shortcode_name" => "option_name"

Comment: Please don't [multipost the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503661/autogenerate-wordpress-shortcodes-using-array).

Answer (score 2):

### Auto-generate shortcodes from an array:

You can try the following *Shortcode Automat*:

```
/**
 * Setup the Shortcode Automat
 *
 */

function shortcode_automat_setup()
{   
    $settings = array(
        "get_address"   =>  "mg_admin_address",
        "get_phone"     =>  "mg_admin_phone",
        "get_fax"       =>  "mg_admin_fax",
        "get_email"     =>  "mg_admin_email",
        "get_hrs_mon"   =>  "mg_work_hrs_mon_frd",
        "get_hrs_sat"   =>  "mg_work_hrs_sat"
    );

    $sc = new ShortCodeAutomat( $settings );
    $sc->generate();
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'shortcode_automat_setup' );
```

You can then test it from your theme/plugin with:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[get_address]" );
echo do_shortcode( "[get_phone]" );
echo do_shortcode( "[get_fax]" );
```

or test it with:

```
[get_address]
[get_phone]
[get_fax]
```

within your post/page content.

Here is our demo class definition:

```
/**
 * class ShortCodeAutomat
 */

class ShortCodeAutomat
{
    protected $settings = array();

    public function  __construct( $settings = array() )
    {
        $this->settings = $settings;
    }

    public function __call( $name, $arguments )
    {
        if( in_array( $name, array_keys( $this->settings ) ) )
        {
            return get_option( sanitize_key( $this->settings[$name] ), '' );
        }
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        foreach( $this->settings as $shortcode => $option )
        {
            add_shortcode( $shortcode, array( $this, $shortcode ) );
        }
    }
} // end class
```